# hosting Django on Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

I'm following a tutorial trying to host Django on apache server, now as I finally installed mod_wsgi using cmd, I try to use the command:

mod_wsgi-express module-config

now i get another bugging error - which is:

```
  Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

(Adwy) C:\Users\Adwy>mod_wsgi-express module-config
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adwy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\mod_wsgi-express-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('mod-wsgi==4.5.20', 'console_scripts', 'mod_wsgi-express')()
  File "c:\users\adwy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "c:\users\adwy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2859, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "c:\users\adwy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2450, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "c:\users\adwy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2456, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "c:\users\adwy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\mod_wsgi\server\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import apxs_config
  File "c:\users\adwy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\mod_wsgi\server\apxs_config.py", line 27
    LIBEXECDIR = 'C:\xampp\apache\/lib'
                    ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-4: truncated \xXX escape
```

I'm looking for help!

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might need to set the MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR environment variable with *forward* slashes. example: "C:/foo/bar/apache"

Take a look at this issue, which looks similar:
https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/345

Comment: Yes, I saw this, and went through it carefully, I already have set the directory to the apache folder, and pip installation for mod_wsgi was satisfied
However, it seems that this error here is different from that addressed at Github despite the same message.

Comment: In The mod_wsgi documentation at 
https://readthedocs.org/projects/modwsgi/downloads/pdf/develop/
mentions something about manual copying of files for successful installation 
also I saw some comment by GrahamDumpleton at Github regarding that, howevere:I’m not sure if this is the problem here, and I don’t understand which files do I need to copy and where to.. I really need to understand this and get this running,

Comment: What is the output of: `echo %MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR%` ?

Comment: Hi Steven, I tried to echo the Directory, and it turns back `%MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR%` - I hope I can solve this , as I'd like to try to test the server

Comment: ok, as I try to use forward slashes as you recommend above , and then try again the `echo %MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR%` , I get a clear path for the directory :  `C:/xampp/apache/` , however, now I try to install again mod_wsgi in the correct dir, but it notify me that `Requirement already satisfied: .. ` , how can I uninstall it to reinstall it correctly? thanks again for your help

Comment: Hi Waly. To uninstall a package use: `pip uninstall <package>` where <package> is the name of the package. Then you should be able to re-run the `pip install` command.

Comment: I checked this https://modwsgi.narkive.com/IkPt4NcM/how-to-uninstall-mod-wsgi-from-httpd-apache-2-2-15-centos-6-6 , and I used your first answer with the Fw slashed , then I used the `pip install https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/develop.zip` to reinstall it correctly, (from: https://modwsgi.narkive.com/IkPt4NcM/how-to-uninstall-mod-wsgi-from-httpd-apache-2-2-15-centos-6-6) - I'm trying to point my problem , however, it works, at least I can run `mod_wsgi-express module-config`, and continue the tutorial .. if you can point out my problem I'd be greatful, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might need to set the MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR environment variable with forward slashes.
example:

```
"C:/foo/bar/apache"
```

To apply this changes you need to reinstall mod_wsgi:

```
pip uninstall mod_wsgi
pip install mod_wsgi
```